# RSS Feed validation: IRI found where URL expected - How to convert IRI link to the valid URL?

Tags: c#, rss, feed, iri

I have created an RSS feed, that contains non-ASCII characters URLs (IRI). That's why it does not validate using [Feed validator](http://feedvalidator.org/).

How important is that validation? As far as I know this is more or less a validation for legacy RSS readers?

Anyway, I would like to know how to convert IRI to URL in C#?

```
http://www.viva.si/Zdrav-način-prehrane/204/Jagodičje
```

to

```
http://www.viva.si/Zdrav-na%C4%8Din-prehrane/204/Jagodi%C4%8Dje
```

Comment: Did you try new Uri(iri).ToString()?

Comment: Yes. "new Uri(iri).ToString()" just returns passed parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
string url = new Uri(iri).AbsoluteUri
```